# Origin of the phrase "do me a favor"

Tags: etymology, history

What is the origin of the phrase "do me a favor?"

First occurrence?

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+me+a+favor&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdo%20me%20a%20favor%3B%2Cc0

Comment: The "origin" is that it's a sequence of words which mean what they mean.

Comment: *The Lucubrations of Isaac Bickerstaff* appeared in [The Tatler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tatler_(1709_journal)) around 1710. It contains the (ironic?) line ***You would do me a favour, young man***, by one Wyat, when someone threatens to stab him through the heart.

Comment: There is an occurrence in [this book from 1687](https://books.google.com/books?id=y_VbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22do+me+a+favour%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN07Hy88XOAhXLVRoKHWAxCAoQ6AEILjAC)

Comment: If mean the **idiom**, which is similar to "Give me a break", ie meaning "Don't be stupid" or "Shut up", rather than just literally asking someone to do you a favour, then you should expand this question to explain that.  http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+me+a+favour

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for the straightforward reading of it, to do someone a kindness. I write historical mysteries set in the late 1800s, so it looks like I'm fine to use it.

Answer (score 1):

First **literary** occurrence seems to be from [**The Rehearsal** 3rd edition 1675](https://books.google.com/books?id=Ce9oAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA3&dq=%22do+me+a+favour%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDkayu9MXOAhXCHxoKHd0lAvE4ChDoAQgkMAE#v=onepage&q=%22do%20me%20a%20favour%22&f=false).

The play was first staged 1671 [(Wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rehearsal_(play)), however that does not necessarily mean that the phrase cannot be older. The word **favour** is from the 13th, or 14th century depending on which meaning applicable for the phrase you prefer.

> Meaning "good will, kind regard" is from mid-14c. in English; sense of "act of kindness, a kindness done" is from late 14c. Meaning "bias, partiality" is from late 14c. Meaning "thing given as a mark of favor" is from late 15c. - [Etymology Online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=favor&allowed_in_frame=0)